# Discrete Noiseless Systems (Channel Capacity)

Tags: limits, information-theory

In Shannon's landmark paper, "A Mathematical Theory of Communications" he discusses the channel capacity of "Discrete Noiseless Systems). From the [paper](http://worrydream.com/refs/Shannon%20-%20A%20Mathematical%20Theory%20of%20Communication.pdf):

> Definition: The capacity C of a discrete channel is given by 
>   ![](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=\lim_{T%20\to%20\infty}%20\frac{\log{N(t)}}{T})
>   
>   where N(T) is the number of allowed signals of duration T.
>   It is easily seen that in the teletype case this reduces to the previous result. It can be shown that the limit
>   in question will exist as a finite number in most cases of interest. Suppose all sequences of the symbols
>   S1,...,Sn are allowed and these symbols have durations t1,...,tn. What is the channel capacity? If N(t)
>   represents the number of sequences of duration t we have 
>   ![](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=N(t)=N(t-t1)%2BN(t-t2)%2B...%2BN(t-tn))

I don't understand the final sequence. If N(t) is the "number of sequences of duration t", isn't N(t-t1) the "number of sequences in t'," where t' is the total duration minus the time it takes to transmit symbol S1?

To illustrate by example, suppose we have 3 symbols S1, S2, S3, which uniformly take 1 second to transmit, i.e., t1=t2=t3=1s

We would expect N(3 seconds) to be 3, correct? But the formula given by Shannon gives 
![](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=N(3)=N(3-1)%2BN(3-1)%2B...%2BN(3-1))

We can clearly see that N(2) is expected to be 2, but the formula thus gives N(3) = 6, twice what was expected.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It is a recursion.

At time $t$ there are $N(t)$ possible signals of length $t$. There are $n$ symbols, so if the last symbol was $S_k$, then there are $N(t-t_k)$ possible signals leading up to $S_k$, which take time $t-t_k$, plus the length of $S_k$
which is $t_k$.

Now add up over all symbols and we get $N(t) = \sum_i N(t-t_i)$.